# How to get the list of files dragged and dropped onto an application binary file on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, qt

On OS X, a common way of running an application on some files is to drop them on the application bundle in Finder. I need to get the list of those files.

I tried to get them from command arguments (like in Windows), but the command line contains only the program path.

How can I get this list using Qt 5.2 or the Cocoa framework?

Comment: You mean how to get the command line arguments within `main()`?

Comment: The question should be clear to anyone who uses a mac!! The action of dropping files on an application executable is probably not commonly done on Windows. Nominating for reopening.

Comment: And this is indeed an excellent question that needed an answer. Kudos to both Igor and Petesh.

Comment: @KubaOber: note that at least two-three people who voted for the closure are experienced Qt developers in my understanding. It has been an unclear question at "I tried to get them from command arguments (like in Windows), but the command line contains only the program path.". Fwiw, I still do not understand that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accept files being opened with your application, you need to accept the `openFile` call for your application delegate, e.g.

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSLog(@"%@", filename);
    return YES;
}
```

Now if you want to accept dragged files onto a window, you have to implement the [`NSDraggingDestination`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, there are several answers here about dealing with that API.

Now for Qt, you need to implement the `event` handler, and deal with the `QEvent::FileOpen` event, who's parameter is a [`QFileOpenEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileopenevent.html) e.g.

```
class MyApp : public QApplication
{
protected:
    bool event(QEvent *);
};

bool
MyApp::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::FileOpen: {
            QFileOpenEvent *evt = static_cast<QFileOpenEvent *>(event));
            // Do something with event->file() - the file that was opened
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return QApplication::event(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is (confusingly) tagged with both objective-c and qt...

Comment: @trojanfoe it is indeed, I had to check my Qt implementation before posting it

Comment: @Petesh: yeah, I saw, and withdrew my downvote instantly. Thanks for caring.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: You can just edit the answer. It's much less abrasive than the whole downvote, nag, unvote hoopla. That's why you can edit any answer, in fact!

Comment: @Kuba: that would be rude. Not every person wishes to correct that themselves, and it is fine if they have their opinion. Moreover, the downvote was not only for that. trojanfoe had other points. There was no harm taken here. Also, it is better if the readers also learn the lesson, so I do not think it is a "hoopla". Comments can also be removed later. See, there was no arguing about it until you came. :) I am actually happy about Petesh's willingness to improve things as opposed to many answerers who take these suggestions very badly.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer That's why. Rude is to down vote and nag. Editing is not rude, that's what the site was designed for.

Comment: IMO, you are misinterpreting that post. :-) If someone is willing to write QT instead of Qt, that is fine as long as I am also entitled to downvote. The tagwiki also writes recommendation as opposed to obligation. Also, it is sometimes too minor an edit. As I wrote already, many people did want to keep that. It is up to them and I would not like to get into a ping-pong game. That being said, I would suggest to refrain from lengthy irrelevant discussions here.